# How to Optimize RAM usage for the following error "Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor."

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-ec2, deep-learning

I am encountering this error on AWS c5.4xlarge instance. Note my batch size is 1 error is

```
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[2976,4464,3]
2018-01-26 02:18:05.895855: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1,2976,4464,3]
Killed
```

I was able to resolve this by stepping up the RAM, but it takes ridiculous 72gb of ram on aws (c5 9xlarge instance) to get it running How do I optimize this by using less RAM note (batch size:1)
`

[image]

I am using the highlighted instance in the above figure which ran out of RAM
I am referring to: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

the config file I am using is:

```
    # Faster R-CNN with Inception Resnet v2, Atrous version;
# Configured for MSCOCO Dataset.
# Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
# well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
# eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
# should be configured.

model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 1
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 600
        max_dimension: 1024
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2'
      first_stage_features_stride: 8
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 8
        width_stride: 8
      }
    }
    first_stage_atrous_rate: 2
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 17
    maxpool_kernel_size: 1
    maxpool_stride: 1
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0003
          schedule {
            step: 0
            learning_rate: .0003
          }
          schedule {
            step: 900000
            learning_rate: .00003
          }
          schedule {
            step: 1200000
            learning_rate: .000003
          }
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_2017_11_08/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 200000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "data/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "data/object-detection.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 8000
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "data/test.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "data/object-detection.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
  num_epochs: 1
}
```

my pbtxt file is:

```
item {
        id: 1
        name: 'name_of_object'  
}
```

Comment: It's an out-of-memory, so the problem is the RAM (since you say you're running on the CPU). From what you show, however, there's nothing that points to the source of the error. The error happens when TF tries to allocate that tensor, but that's, depending on the datatype, about 160MBs of RAM (ot twice that if you're using `int64` or `double`). What you're not showing, however, is what *else* is already allocated before that. It may well be that your graph contains too many tensors, or maybe you're loading the full dataset in RAM. Post the code and we might be more helpful.

Comment: Show us the code

Comment: I posted the code below (not in comments due to a large size of training.config file). I was able to resolve this issue I am looking to optimize the memory usage RAM now

Comment: I was unaware that question gets downvoted if I post additional info in answer session and not edit the question itself, I edited the question now.